# Refresh ViewPart after maximize

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

How can I refresh my ViewPart on maximizing? Which listener is responsible for that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a resize listener.

Answer (score 0):

Add a ControlListener to the view's composite. The control listener is invoked when the view is resized or moved.